# Is Xamarin.Forms shell appropriate to do this navigation/Tabs mix flow?

Tags: xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms app, I have to implement this flow without Shell :
A splahscreen, then a page with Title bar showing a list. When user clicks on an list item, then a tabbar page with still the title bar and a back button to go back to previous page.
[image]

While I could implement it with standard Xamarin.Forms app, I consider using "Shell" because it has some advantages.
Question: Is shell appropriate for a such complicated flow?

Comment: Any update on this Question , did you try the Flyout ?

Answer (score 0):

Made a small Flyout example so i added 3 pages `Paris` , `Tokyo` and `Tokyo2`.
Starts with the Flyout open and there are 2 items Paris and Tokyo.
Paris is normal Page and Tokoy has a Tab1 and Tab2 , these are 2 different pages.

Put i on Github https://github.com/borisoprit/ShellSOexample

Code i used :

```
  <ShellItem FlyoutItemIsVisible="True" Route="Startpage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" Route="home" />
</ShellItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Paris" >

    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Paris}" Route="home" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Tokyo" >


    <Tab Title="Tab1">

        <ShellContent Title="Tab1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Tokyo}" Route="Tokyo" />
       
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Tab2">

        <ShellContent Title="Tab 2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Tokyo2}" Route="Tokyo2" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

To start with Flyout put this in App.xaml.cs

```
  Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = true;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi BH; tried your solution, but unfortunately it does not answer my question. It is using Flyouts, but I need standard navigation. i.e. the screen after the splash screen must be fullscreen, with a navigation bar. From the next screen (Tokyo), I must to go back to previous screen with back button in navigation bar. There are plenty of examples on internet (especially James Montemagno podcasts) showing how to mix flyout & tabs, but I don't find useful resources to show how to mix navigation & tabs, especially the specific case I ask about in my post.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective,it's possible to implement this flow without Shell.Below is the solution for your reference.

1.The Launch page is a splash screen,you can refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/splashscreen

2.The second page is composed of the navigation and the most important thing is that you need transfer the tapped listview item to the third page which is a Tabbed Page.Below is the code for your reference:

**Code in Xmal:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
         NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
         x:Class="AppMark.View.ListPage"
         Padding="0,20,0,0"
         >

<StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
    <Label Text="Select a place" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView"  SeparatorColor="Black" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="listView_ItemTapped" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding City}"></Label>
                            <Label Text=">" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label Text=">"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code Behind:**
    
        public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        listView.ItemsSource = new List<CityName>
        {
            new CityName{ City  = "Pairs"},
            new CityName{ City  = "Tokyo"},
            new CityName{ City  = "Berlin"},
            new CityName{ City  = "Los Angeles"},
        };
    }

    private async void listView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        CityName city = (CityName)e.Item;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedPage1(city));
    }
}
```

3.The third Page is a Tabbed Page and below is the code behind for your reference:

```
    public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public TabbedPage1(CityName city)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = city.City.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Teckel Cruel, Could U please help confirm if this resolves your issue?